# How to modify relation when converting to json?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a Parent that hasMany children:

```
class Parent extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
    }
}


class Child extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
    }
}
```

Child model has only 2 attributes: `parent_id` and `value`. I want to "pluck" value when converting parent to json so that instead of

```
{
  "name": "name1",
  "children": [
    {
      "value": "value1"
    },
    {
      "value": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get

```
{
  "name": "name1",
  "children": [
    "value1",
    "value2"
  ]
}
```

I know that it can be accomplished by declaring a new `getValuesAttribute` and adding `protected $appends = ['values'];` to the Parent model but I want to do so without renaming the attribute (I want values to be in `children` array and not in `values` array). If I define mutator attribute with the same name as relation it obviously results in errors.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [Fractal](https://fractal.thephpleague.com) to separate the representation of your data from the model. If you define a Fractal transformer to match the structure you want, you can pass the data to the transformer in your controller and change the structure of the JSON without touching the model.

EDIT: Laravel 5.5 introduced [resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources), which are a simpler alternative to Fractal, but do basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What if you will do something like that:

```
$parent->children = $parent->children->pluck('value');

return $parent->toJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `jsonSerialize` function in you `Parent` model:

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return [
       'name' => $this->name,
       'children' => $this->children->pluck('value')->toArray(),
    ]
}
```

Doing that you will receive the correct output when calling the `toJson()` method or when returning the model as a json response (that internally calls `toJson()`.